# jQuery / javascript: find character and wrap the word(s) containing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to wrap all words in my texts that contain one or more hyphens "-" into a span so I can add a no-linebreak css rule. Unfortunately I have no idea how to achieve this. Any ideas/hints would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Example:

```
    Before: <p>This product is ready-to-use.</p>
    After:  <p>This product is <span class="nbr">ready-to-use</span>.</p>
```

Comment: Well, you already tagged your question with regex. Try to look into [`string.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: No-one will write it for you. Check out regular expressions and so forth. You need to come back with a specific question relating to a problem, and tell us what you have already tried.

Comment: SO is for helping with certain problem, not doing entire work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex does the trick:

```
((\w+-)+\w+)(?![^<]*\>)
```

The `((\w+-)+\w+)` part is a regex which matches words separated by hyphens. The part after the `(?!` makes sure that the expression is not followed by a `>` which has a `<` before it. This is to avoid matching words separated by hyphens inside html tags (example: `<div class="style: margin-left">`. You probably wouldn't like to match that `margin-left`).

In order to use the regex in javascript you have to use a raw string and also add parenthesis around the regex to capture the matched value as a group:

```
text.replace(/(((\w+-)+\w+)(?![^<]*\>))/m, '<span class="nbr">$1</span>');
```

Comment: +1 for solving the html tag issue.

Comment: great, thanks. now i feel really stupid because I can't make the regex work ... another hint maybe?
       jQuery('.mytext').each(function() {
    var curTxt = jQuery(this).html();
    var newTxt = curTxt.replace('((\w+-)+\w+)(?![^<]*\>)', '<span class="nbr">$1</span>');
    jQuery(this).html(newTxt);
   });

Comment: I've added a functional code to demonstrate how to use it in Javascript. See above.

Comment: Note tag workaround is not completely watertight - eg `word-word > word` in text content won't match; a browser *may* escape that to `&gt;` but is not obliged to. Also if you are doing it to a live document with `innerHTML`/`html()` then you are serialising, re-parsing and completely replacing each `.mytext` element, which will lose any non-serialisable content in that element such as form field values and event handlers.

Comment: To tackle the problems @bobince mentions, I suppose you could recursively iterate over `parentNode.childNodes` and apply a slightly different replace for every `textNode` you find. That way, you leave it to the DOM to distinguish between a `>` in the text and a `>` that's part of an element. Also this won't fiddle with nodes that don't need fiddling, leaving form field values and event handles in tact.

Comment: Ah, turns out Linguigi does that for you, see @Prinzhorn's answer below

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a lib some time ago. It works on DOM text nodes, so it avoids parsing HTML using RegEx (which is not possible).

https://github.com/prinzhorn/linguigi

Example

```
var ling = new Linguigi();

ling.eachToken(/[\w-]+/, true, function(token) {
    return '<span class="nbr">' + token + '</span>';
});
```

You may want to use a regex that matches your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String text = "<p>This product is ready-to-use.</p>";
    text = text.replaceAll("(\\w+-(\\w+-?)+)", "<span class=\"nbr\">$1</span>");
    System.out.println(text);
```

Comment: Actually this should be done with JavaScript not Java.